# Performing Gauss-Jordan elimination on a matrix in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, mathematics, matrix

I have this small "framework" for representing matrices with entries of primitive type `double`, and performing Gauss-Jordan elimination (for solving systems of linear equations). My main concern is cohesion of my code, but I would be glad to hear whatever comes to mind.

**GaussJordanElimination.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.math.linear;

import static net.coderodde.math.linear.Utils.checkNotInfinite;
import static net.coderodde.math.linear.Utils.checkNotNaN;
import static net.coderodde.math.linear.Utils.checkNotNegative;
import static net.coderodde.math.linear.Utils.checkNotNull;

/**
 * This class provides a static method performing Gauss-Jordan elimination on an
 * input matrix.
 */
public class GaussJordanElimination {

    /**
     * Defines the default epsilon for comparison.
     */
    private static final double DEFAULT_EPSILON = 1E-6;

    /**
     * Defines the sentinel value for any index of a non-valid row.
     */
    private static final int ROW_NOT_FOUND = -1;

    /**
     * Caches the actual matrix.
     */
    private final double[][] m;

    /**
     * The epsilon value for comparisons.
     */
    private final double epsilon;

    /**
     * Performs Gauss-Jordan elimination on the input matrix using given 
     * epsilon.
     * 
     * @param matrix  the matrix to eliminate.
     * @param epsilon the epsilon value used for comparisons.
     * @return        the rank of the resulting matrix.
     */
    public static int solve(final Matrix matrix, final double epsilon) {
        return new GaussJordanElimination(matrix.m, epsilon).eliminate();
    }

    /**
     * Performs Gauss-Jordan elimination on the input matrix using default 
     * epsilon.
     * 
     * @param matrix the matrix to eliminate.
     * @return       the rank of the resulting matrix.
     */
    public static int solve(final Matrix matrix) {
        return solve(matrix, DEFAULT_EPSILON);
    }

    /**
     * Returns <code>true</code> if it is certain that the system of linear 
     * equations represented by the input matrix has no solutions. If there is 
     * a chance of feasibility, returns <code>false</code>. Uses the default 
     * epsilon.
     * 
     * @param matrix  the matrix to check.
     * @return <code>true</code> if there is no solution of the system
     *         represented by the matrix and otherwise <code>false</code> is 
     *         returned.
     */
    public static boolean isNotFeasible(final Matrix matrix) {
        return isNotFeasible(matrix, DEFAULT_EPSILON);
    }

    /**
     * Returns <code>true</code> if it is certain that the system of linear 
     * equations represented by the input matrix has no solutions. If there is 
     * a chance of feasibility, returns <code>false</code>.
     * 
     * @param matrix  the matrix to check.
     * @param epsilon the comparison epsilon.
     * @return <code>true</code> if there is no solution of the system
     *         represented by the matrix and otherwise <code>false</code> is 
     *         returned.
     */
    public static boolean isNotFeasible(final Matrix matrix,
                                        final double epsilon) {
        checkNotNaN(epsilon, "The input epsilon is NaN.");
        checkNotInfinite(epsilon, "The input epsilon is infinite: " + epsilon);
        checkNotNegative(epsilon, "The input epsilon is negative: " + epsilon);

        outer:
        for (int r = 0; r < matrix.getHeight(); ++r) {
            for (int c = 0; c < matrix.getWidth() - 1; ++c) {
                if (!epsilonEquals(0.0, matrix.get(c, r), epsilon)) { 
                    continue outer;
                }
            }

            if (!epsilonEquals(0.0, 
                               matrix.get(matrix.getWidth() - 1, r), 
                               epsilon)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Constructs this eliminator.
     * 
     * @param m       the matrix to eliminate.
     * @param epsilon the epsilon value for comparisons.
     */
    private GaussJordanElimination(final double[][] m, final double epsilon) {
        checkNotNull(m, "The input matrix is null.");
        checkNotNaN(epsilon, "The input epsilon is NaN.");
        checkNotInfinite(epsilon, "The input epsilon is infinite: " + epsilon);
        checkNotNegative(epsilon, "The input epsilon is negative: " + epsilon);

        this.m = m;
        this.epsilon = epsilon;
    }

    /**
     * Performs the actual elimination.
     * 
     * @return the rank of the resulting matrix.
     */
    private int eliminate() {
        int rowsProcessed = 0;

        for (int k = 0; k != m[0].length; ++k) {
            int ur = findUpmostRowWithPivotAtColumn(k, rowsProcessed);

            if (ur == ROW_NOT_FOUND) {
                continue;
            }

            swapRows(ur, rowsProcessed);
            scaleRow(rowsProcessed, 1.0 / m[rowsProcessed][k]);

            for (int r = 0; r != m.length; ++r) {
                if (r != rowsProcessed) {
                    addToRowMultipleOfAnotherRow(
                            r,  
                            rowsProcessed, 
                            -m[r][k] / m[rowsProcessed][k]);
                }
            }

            ++rowsProcessed;
        }

        return rowsProcessed;
    }

    /**
     * Returns <code>true</code> if <code>a</code> and <code>b</code> are within
     * <code>epsilon</code> from each other.
     * 
     * @param a       the first value.
     * @param b       the second value.
     * @param epsilon the maximum allowed distance.
     * @return        <code>true</code> if <code>a</code> and <code>b</code> are
     *                within <code>epsilon</code> from each other.
     */
    public static boolean epsilonEquals(final double a, 
                                        final double b,
                                        final double epsilon) {
        return Math.abs(a - b) <= epsilon;
    }

    /**
     * Checks the multiplication factor.
     * 
     * @param factor the factor value to check.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the factor is <code>NaN</code> or is
     *                                  infinite.
     */
    private static void checkFactor(final double factor) {
        checkNotNaN(factor, "The factor is NaN.");
        checkNotInfinite(factor, "The factor is infinite: " + factor);
    }

    /**
     * Implements an elementary matrix operation of adding a multiple of one row
     * to another.
     * 
     * @param targetRowIndex the index of the row to which to add.
     * @param sourceRowIndex the index of the row which is added.
     * @param factor         the factor by which to multiply each entry of the
     *                       source row.
     */
    private void addToRowMultipleOfAnotherRow(final int targetRowIndex,
                                              final int sourceRowIndex,
                                              final double factor) {
        checkFactor(factor);
        for (int i = 0; i != m[0].length; ++i) {
            m[targetRowIndex][i] += m[sourceRowIndex][i] * factor;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Swaps to rows with given indices.
     * 
     * @param rowIndex1 the index of a row.
     * @param rowIndex2 the index of another row.
     */
    private void swapRows(final int rowIndex1, final int rowIndex2) {
        final double[] tmp = m[rowIndex1];
        m[rowIndex1] = m[rowIndex2];
        m[rowIndex2] = tmp;
    }

    /**
     * Skips the first <code>skipRows</code> rows in the matrix and returns 
     * the index of a row containing non-zero value at column 
     * <code>columnIndex</code>.
     * 
     * @param columnIndex the index of the target column.
     * @param skipRows    the amount of uppermost rows to skip.
     * @return            a row index.
     */
    private int findUpmostRowWithPivotAtColumn(final int columnIndex,
                                               final int skipRows) {
        for (int i = skipRows; i < m.length; ++i) {
            if (!epsilonEquals(m[i][columnIndex], 0.0, epsilon)) {
                return i;
            }
        }

        return ROW_NOT_FOUND;
    }

    /**
     * Multiplies each entry of the specified matrix row by a given factor.
     * 
     * @param rowIndex the index of the row.
     * @param factor   the multiplication factor.
     */
    private void scaleRow(final int rowIndex, final double factor) {
        checkFactor(factor);
        final double[] row = m[rowIndex];
        for (int i = 0; i != row.length; ++i) {
            row[i] *= factor;
        }
    }   
}
```

**Matrix.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.math.linear;

/**
 * This class implements a matrix of <code>double</code> entries.
 */
public class Matrix implements Cloneable {

    /**
     * The minimum allowed width of a matrix.
     */
    private static final int MINIMUM_WIDTH = 1;

    /**
     * The minimum allowed height of a matrix.
     */
    private static final int MINIMUM_HEIGHT = 1;

    /**
     * The actual storage of entries. This field is declared package private as
     * to speed up the actual matrix operations.
     */
    final double[][] m;

    /**
     * Constructs a new matrix with width <code>width</code> and height       
     * <code>height</code>.
     * 
     * @param width  the width of the matrix.
     * @param height the height of the matrix.
     */
    public Matrix(final int width, final int height) {
        checkWidth(width);
        checkHeight(height);
        m = new double[height][width];
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a new matrix using the specified entries.
     * 
     * @param data the data matrix containing the entries.
     */
    public Matrix(final double[][] data) {
        int h = data.length;
        int w = 0;

        for (final double[] row : data) {
            w = Math.max(w, row.length);
        }

        m = new double[h][w];

        for (int r = 0; r != data.length; ++r) {
            for (int c = 0; c != data[r].length; ++c) {
                m[r][c] = data[r][c];
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the height of this matrix.
     * 
     * @return the height.
     */
    public int getHeight() {
        return m.length;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the width of this matrix.
     * 
     * @return the width. 
     */
    public int getWidth() {
        return m[0].length;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the entry at row <code>y</code> column <code>x</code>. (Both 
     * indices start at zero.)
     * 
     * @param x the column index of the entry.
     * @param y the row index of the entry.
     * @return a matrix entry.
     */
    public double get(final int x, final int y) {
        checkColumnIndex(x);
        checkRowIndex(y);
        return m[y][x];
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value for the entry at row <code>y</code> column <code>x</code>.
     * (Both indices start at zero.)
     * 
     * @param x     the column index.
     * @param y     the row index.
     * @param value the new value to set.
     * @return      the old value.
     */
    public double set(final int x, final int y, final double value) {
        checkColumnIndex(x);
        checkRowIndex(y);
        final double old = m[y][x];
        m[y][x] = value;
        return old;
    }

    /**
     * Returns another matrix with exactly same contents as this matrix.
     * 
     * @return the clone matrix.
     */
    @Override
    public Matrix clone() {
        final Matrix clone = new Matrix(getWidth(), getHeight());

        for (int row = 0; row < getHeight(); ++row) {
            for (int column = 0; column < getWidth(); ++column) {
                clone.set(column, row, get(column, row));
            }
        }

        return clone;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        final String formatString = "%+f ";

        for (int r = 0; r < getHeight(); ++r) {
            for (int c = 0; c < getWidth(); ++c) {
                sb.append(String.format(formatString, get(c, r)));
            }

            sb.append('\n');
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Checks the width.
     * 
     * @param width the width to check.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the width is too small.
     */
    private void checkWidth(final int width) {
        if (width < MINIMUM_WIDTH) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "The matrix width is too small. " + 
            "Requested width: " + width + ", " + 
            "mimimum allowed: " + MINIMUM_WIDTH);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks the height.
     * 
     * @param height the height to check.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the height is too small.
     */
    private void checkHeight(final int height) {
        if (height < MINIMUM_HEIGHT) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "The matrix width is too small. " + 
            "Requested width: " + height + ", " + 
            "mimimum allowed: " + MINIMUM_HEIGHT);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks that the given row index is valid.
     * 
     * @param rowIndex the index of a row to check.
     * @throws IllegalArgumenException if the index is out of bounds.
     */
    private void checkRowIndex(final int rowIndex) {
        if (rowIndex < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "Row index is negative: " + rowIndex);
        }

        if (rowIndex >= m.length) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "Row index is too large. " +
            "Received: " + rowIndex + ", the height of the matrix: " +
            m.length);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks that the given column index is valid.
     * 
     * @param columnIndex the index of a column to check.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the index is out of bounds.
     */
    private void checkColumnIndex(final int columnIndex) {
        if (columnIndex < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "Column index is negative: " + columnIndex);
        }

        if (columnIndex >= m[0].length) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "Column index is too large. " +
            "Received: " + columnIndex + ", the width of the matrix: " +
            m[0].length);
        }
    }
}
```

**Utils.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.math.linear;

/**
 * This class defines some common utility methods.
 */
public class Utils {

    /**
     * Checks that the input number is not infinite and if it is, throws
     * an exception with the specified message.
     * 
     * @param value  the value to check.
     * @param errmsg the message to pass to the exception upon failure.
     */
    public static void checkNotInfinite(final double value, 
                                        final String errmsg) {
        if (Double.isInfinite(value)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(errmsg);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks that the input number is not <code>NaN</code> and if it is,
     * throws an exception with the specified message.
     * 
     * @param value  the value to check.
     * @param errmsg the message to pass to the exception upon failure.
     */
    public static void checkNotNaN(final double value, final String errmsg) {
        if (Double.isNaN(value)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The value is NaN.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks that the input number is not negative and if it is, throws an
     * exception with the specified message.
     * 
     * @param value  the value to check.
     * @param errmsg the message to pass to the exception upon failure.
     */
    public static void checkNotNegative(final double value, 
                                        final String errmsg) {
        if (value < 0.0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(errmsg);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks that the input reference is not <code>null</code> and if it is,
     * throw an exception with the supplied error message.
     * 
     * @param o      the reference to check.
     * @param errmsg the error message to pass to the exception upon failure.
     */
    public static void checkNotNull(final Object o, final String errmsg) {
        if (o == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(errmsg);
        }
    }
}
```

**Demo.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.math.linear;

import java.util.Random;
import static net.coderodde.math.linear.GaussJordanElimination.isNotFeasible;

/**
 * This class implements a demonstration.
 */
public class Demo {

    private static final String GAY_BAR;

    static {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(80);

        for (int i = 0; i < 80; ++i) {
            sb.append('-');
        }

        GAY_BAR = sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        helloWorldDemo();
        bar();
        laaargggeeeDemmoo();
    }

    private static void helloWorldDemo() {
        Matrix m = new Matrix(new double[][] {
            { 1.0, 3.0, -2.0, 5.0 }, 
            { 3.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0  }, 
            { 2.0, 4.0, 3.0, 8.0  }, 
        });

        System.out.println(m);

        int rank = GaussJordanElimination.solve(m);

        System.out.println(m);
        System.out.println("Rank: " + rank);
        System.out.println("Feasible: " + isNotFeasible(m));

        bar();

        m = new Matrix(new double[][] {
            { 1.0, 3.0, -2.0, 5.0 }, 
            { 3.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0  }, 
            { 4.0, 8.0, 6.0, 16.0 },
            { 2.0, 4.0, 3.0, 8.0  }, 
            { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -5.0 },
        });

        System.out.println(m);

        rank = GaussJordanElimination.solve(m);

        System.out.println(m);
        System.out.println("Rank: " + rank);
        System.out.println("Feasible: " + isNotFeasible(m));

        bar();

        m = new Matrix(new double[][] {
            { 1.0, 3.0, -2.0, 5.0 }, 
            { 3.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0  },
            { 3.0, 5.0, 6.0, 8.0  },
        });

        System.out.println(m);

        rank = GaussJordanElimination.solve(m);

        System.out.println(m);
        System.out.println("Rank: " + rank);
        System.out.println("Feasible: " + isNotFeasible(m));
    }

    private static void bar() {
        System.out.println(GAY_BAR);
    }

    private static void laaargggeeeDemmoo() {
        final long seed = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final Random rnd = new Random(seed);
        final Matrix m = new Matrix(1000, 500);

        System.out.println("Seed: " + seed);

        for (int r = 0; r < m.getHeight(); ++r) {
            for (int c = 0; c < m.getWidth(); ++c) {
                m.set(c, r, rnd.nextInt(101) - 50);
            }
        }

        long ta = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int rank = GaussJordanElimination.solve(m);
        long tb = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Rank: " + rank + ", time: " + (tb - ta) + " ms.");
        System.out.println("Feasible: " + isNotFeasible(m));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## GaussJordanElimination.java

```
/**
 * Caches the actual matrix.
 */
private final double[][] m;
```

You could use more descriptive name that `m` maybe something like `content` which can tell me what is `m` without to read the comment.

```
public static int solve(final Matrix matrix, final double epsilon) {
        return new GaussJordanElimination(matrix.m, epsilon).eliminate();
    }
```

If you really need `matrix.m` as argument why you pass the whole matrix object ?

```
if (!epsilonEquals(0.0, matrix.get(c, r), epsilon)) { 
     continue outer;
}
```

There is `0.0` as magic number but what is its purpose - this can be some variable with proper name.

Also you alternate `public` and `private` methods - it would be better if you group them let say first public and below private methods.

```
  public static boolean epsilonEquals(final double a, 
                                        final double b,
                                        final double epsilon) {
        return Math.abs(a - b) <= epsilon;
    }
```

`epsilonEquals()` is not appropriate for boolean methods - maybe something like `isInEpsilonRange()` (just as example) would be more descriptive.

```
private void swapRows(final int rowIndex1, final int rowIndex2)
```

Instead `rowIndex*` you could use `first(second)RowIndex` or something similar.

## Matrix.java

```
public double get(final int x, final int y)
```

You could use `columnIndex` and `rowIndex` instead `x` and `y`.

## Utils.java

Maybe should be named to something like `Validator` with `validateX()` methods.
All of this methods (for now) perform some validation on input data.

I hope that this will help you :)